# Javascript str.replace with regex with double searchvalue

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

This code

```
var i = '[0]';
i.replace(/\[|\]/, '');
```

returns `i = '0]'`

I want to use `.replace` function to convert`i = '0'`;

Comment: Use the `g` flag.

Comment: it works:) please post an answer, so I can choose you. Does it mean that without 'g' it just finds the first match only?

Comment: It finds the first occurence of `/\[|\]/`, which is `[`. I generally won’t post answers without searching for duplicate targets first.

Comment: add the g flag to expration

Comment: .replace(/\[/, '').replace(/\]/);

Comment: `var i = '[0]';
i.replace(/\[|\]/g, '');` will output '0' I just added if somebody becomes confused about where to add 'g' flag.

Answer (score 1):

edit the code and use `g` flag

```
var i = '[0]';
i.replace(/\[|\]/g, '');
```